# How to solve H2 "Error executing DDL" error?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, orm, h2

I want to create table via H2 in springboot, but when I run I've got following error;

> org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
>       org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table bank_account (id bigint not null, balance
>   double not null, full name varchar(128) not null, primary key (id))"
>   via JDBC Statement

...

data.sql:

```
Insert into Bank_Account(ID, Full_Name, Balance) values (1, 'Ibrahim', 2500);
Insert into Bank_Account(ID, Full_Name, Balance) values (2, 'Ates', 4210);
```

pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Application.properties;

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

What did I miss?

---

solution;

Problem was caused by entity's column name. I ve changed entity named "Full Name" to "Full_Name", then problem was solved.

Comment: show your hibnerate, db properties from your application.propeties file

Comment: I added end of question...

Comment: Ok, is there an entity which maps to Bank_Account table?  show it if yes

Comment: Yes. Like following i have;  @Entity
@Table(name="Bank_Account")
public class BankAccount {

... }

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem is due to the fact that you are trying to init the database both using hibernate auto-ddl tool as well as the Spring Boots schema.sql file.

According to the docs:

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema
>   or use `schema.sql`, but **you cannot do both**. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use `schema.sql`.

So either remove the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` proprerty or the `schema.sql` file so that Spring Boot does not try to pick it up.

Comment: Hi, I removed schema.sql file. But it is not working still.